# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR) on line 10

Tags: php

So i get the error

> "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR) in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/classes/class.ManageUsers.php on line 10",

does anyone know what part of the syntax is wrong? Below is the relevant class.

```
5    class ManageUsers {
6   public $link;
7   
8   function __construct(){
9       $db_connection = new dbConnection();
10      $this->link = db_connection->connect();
11      return $this->link;
12  }
```

Comment: you need to test all the answer that are given. and the most suitable answer will be marked by you. also you can vote up other helpful solution also if possible. it will help future visitors. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`db_connection->connect();` should be `$db_connection->connect();` notice the missing `$`